# Look-ahead regular expression alternative

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch snapshot restore module and trying to get this to work:

```
  "rename_pattern": "^foo_(.+)(_bar)?$",
  "rename_replacement": "$1",
```

Meaning the string must start with foo_, followed by any number of characters, and it must end with _bar, which is optional. So both foo_some_string_bar and foo_some_string must end up as some_string. foo_some_string_bar_bar must end up as some_string_bar.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

p.s: I managed to do it like this:

```
$ echo foo_some_string | sed -nE '/^foo_(((.+)_bar)|(.+))$/s//\3\4/p'
some_string
$ echo foo_some_string_bar | sed -nE '/^foo_(((.+)_bar)|(.+))$/s//\3\4/p'
some_string
$ echo foo_some_string_bar_bar | sed -nE '/^foo_(((.+)_bar)|(.+))$/s//\3\4/p'
some_string_bar
$
```

It works, but it's sooo tricky and cumbersome.

Comment: Why are you showing `sed` examples if you are trying to find a solution in  ElasticSearch ?

Comment: Not in `sed` but in other flavors you can use `^foo_(.+?)(_bar)?$`

Comment: sed uses extended regular expression syntax, which is probably the case for ElasticSearch, which seems to be using Apache Lucene RE engine under the hood.

Comment: So is it a sed related question? Please consider retagging.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, no, it's an ElasticSearch regular expression question, I just tested it out in sed. And then I tried it in ElasticSearch to do a snapshot restore: it also worked.

Comment: If you found an answer that works, please post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Replacing this:

```
  "rename_pattern": "^foo_(.+)(_bar)?$",
  "rename_replacement": "$1",
```

with this:

```
  "rename_pattern": "^foo_(((.+)_bar)|(.+))$",
  "rename_replacement": "$3$4",
```

Solved the problem. The problem was that (.+)(_bar)?$ greedily matched everything no matter what. But the awkward | patterns do what I need: either match everything before _bar at the end, or just match the whole remainder if the string doesn't end with _bar.